# ploting scatter plot with 2D list

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have two set of data, the first set of data is a 1D list, and the second set of data is a 2D list. I want to plot a scatter figure with the first set of data being x, and the second set of data being y. However, the length of the element in the 2D list is not identical, for example, x=[1,2,3] y = [[1,2], [3,4,5],[7,6]], so when I try to plot, I get the warning

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

How to fix this problem? Thanks

Comment: I am sorry I did not post my code here because it is too long and I have already outlined the problem in my description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you don't want to plot the points when they don't exist in y. You can replace these with None, the following should work:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Define arrays
x = [1,2,3]
y = [[1,2], [3,4,5],[7,6]]

#Padd y with None to length of x
for i in y:
    while len(i) < len(x):
        i.append(None)

for yn in y:
    plt.scatter(x,yn)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but the thing is there are lots of element in y, it is impossible to add None by hand for each element.

Comment: You could use some form of loop to pad the arrays as needed, I've edited my answer.